# Base-b Representations of Integers [collecting proofs]

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To this day, I find different proofs of this elementary theory interesting. So I want to ask people here at MSE to show as many different answers to this problem as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: we have to express the number of the following set of sticks in base $4$
$$
|||||||||||||||||||||||
$$
First step: group the sticks in $4$-tuples
$$
\underbrace{||||\qquad ||||\qquad ||||\qquad ||||\qquad||||}%
_{\text{to step 2}}\qquad |||
$$
Second step: count the $4$-tuples; we may as well use a stick to represent them
$$
|||||
$$
Do the same as before
$$
\underbrace{||||}_{\text{to step 3}} \qquad |
$$
Third step: count the $4$-tuples; we may as well use a stick to represent them
$$
|
$$

End.

The representation is $113$.

## More formal method

### Existence

We know how to represent $0$ in base $b$. Suppose $n>0$ and that, by induction hypothesis, we know how to represent every number less than $n$ in base $b$. Then we can do
$$
n=bm+r
$$
with $0\le r<b$. Observe that $m<n$, so we can represent $m$ in base $b$:
$$
m=m_{s}b^{s}+m_{s-1}b^{s-1}+\dots+m_1b+m_0
$$
and therefore
$$
n=(m_{s}b^{s}+m_{s-1}b^{s-1}+\dots+m_1b+m_0)b+r
$$
Set $t=s+1$, $n_0=r$ and $n_k=m_{k-1}$ for $k=1,2,\dots,t$; then
$$
n=n_tb^t+n_{t-1}b^{t-1}+\dots+n_1b+n_0
$$

### Uniqueness

Suppose $n=x_sb^s+\dots+x_1b+x_0=y_tb^t+\dots+y_1b+y_0$. Then
$$
n\equiv x_0\pmod{b}
\qquad
n\equiv y_0\pmod{b}
$$
so $x_0=y_0$, because digits are in the interval $[0..(b-1)]$.

Suppose uniqueness holds for numbers $<n$; then
$$
\frac{n-x_0}{b}=\frac{n-y_0}{b}<n
$$
and the induction hypothesis yields $s=t$ and
$$
x_k=y_k\quad (k=1,2,\dots,s)
$$
The base case for $n=0$ is obvious.